# Installing a npm pack on two different branches

Tags: git, npm

I have a ***npm pack*** on a branch that we will call **BRANCH 1**. I need the same pack on a different branch, **BRANCH 2**, but BRANCH 1 still hasn't pass the code review phase, so it isn't merged yet and a pull from "master" isn't practicable.

The question it's pretty easy: can I install the same pack on BRANCH 2 without any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. The files affected are `package.json`, `package-lock.json`. If you don't want to touch these files you could install with `--no-save`. Then update your second branch from the master when the first branch is merged.